# Access internet on Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

Recentely, I deploy a worker role that it will connect to internet and attemp to access some websites (For example: `http://somewebsite.redmond.corp.microsoft.com/en-us/library/`).

It successfully access the websites on my development machine running on emulator. But on the Azure virual machine that I deploy my worker role to, it is not able to access the websites. I try to open the websites on VM browering in IE, it is also not able to.

Have u emcounter similar issues? How do u deal with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with accessing the Internet. The URL you provided isn't publicly visible (at least I can't access it from my machine). This means you're attempting to visit a URL behind a firewall, possibly requiring a VPN to access.

Windows Azure VM's, whether worker roles, web roles, or Virtual Machines, are in a public cloud and not behind any firewall. If you wanted to access it from a Windows Azure VM, you'd need to set up a Virtual Network, introduced in the Spring 2012 update. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156007.aspx).

Comment: That means public sites lets say google.com, is directly accesible by Azure VM?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Elevated premissions for this. Once,I tried to access internet through RDP of a Role, It was working at that time hence it should be possible for you to access internet. But if are trying to download exes and execute, I Think that isn't possible.Please post you Results here.

Regards,
Vijay.